# Trying to understand pattern to use with BeginInvoke()

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I have two TextBlock’s that I am positioning consecutively on a Canvas.  The first case works fine:

```
TextBlock text1 = new TextBlock();
text1.Text = "Not ";
text1.FontSize = 18;
Canvas.SetTop(text1, 20);
Canvas.SetLeft(text1, 20);
canvas.Children.Add(text1);

TextBlock text2 = new TextBlock();
text2.Text = "bad!";
text2.FontSize = 18;
Canvas.SetTop(text2, 20);
canvas.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, 
  new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate(Object state)
  {
    Canvas.SetLeft(text2, 20 + text1.ActualWidth);
    return null;
  }
  ), null);
canvas.Children.Add(text2);
```

Result:

[image]

However, the second case, which does not use BeginInvoke(), fails:

```
TextBlock text1 = new TextBlock();
text1.Text = "Not ";
text1.FontSize = 18;
Canvas.SetTop(text1, 20);
Canvas.SetLeft(text1, 20);
canvas.Children.Add(text1);

TextBlock text2 = new TextBlock();
text2.Text = "bad!";
text2.FontSize = 18;
Canvas.SetTop(text2, 20);
Canvas.SetLeft(text2, 20 + text1.ActualWidth); // ActualWidth is zero.
canvas.Children.Add(text2);
```

Result:

[image]

Now, I know that in the second case, the WPF rendering has not happened yet.  My question is simply this: **What is the preferred pattern to use in such a case where I need to know the actual coordinate values for UI controls which are only available after rendering has taken place?**

(e.g. Is the approach, where BeginInvoke() is used, a good solution?  Should the entire code be enclosed in a giant BeginInvoke()?)

Comment: Dude, I have no idea what you're doing, but your code is horrible. Why are you creating UI elements in code? That's what XAML is for.

Comment: The words will be read in at run time.  I cannot hardcode them into XAML.

Comment: Then Create an `ItemsControl` or something. You could also put these together in a single TextBlock.  Otherwise use a `WrapPanel` or something. the Canvas is not the right container for Text. WPF is not winforms. Your code is still horrible. If properties are the same between different `TextBlock`s, use a XAML-defined Style. Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the right way to implement it in WPF.

Comment: I understand, and thanks for your suggestions.  But you are not answering the actual question.

Comment: Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the right way to implement it in WPF.

Comment: I need to be able to display a sentence that I read from a document.  Then, I need to be able to select words and move them around.  And to do this, I chose a Canvas.  I would not have the same flexibility with a WrapPanel or the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:

`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` queues the operation in the Dispatcher's "pending jobs" queue. This allows it to be able to process the addition of the first UI element, and run the `Layout` and `Render` passes before continuing to execute your code.

Therefore, when your code is run, the size of the first TextBlock has already been calculated, and you can get it.

*Again, I don't know what you're attempting to do, but creating UI elements in code is usually a sign of a poor design. WPF is not winforms and the WPF ways are completely different from the horrible hacks required to do anything in winforms.*

Edit:

This is my approach using a `WrapPanel` and some `RenderTransform`:

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.MovingWords"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MovingWords" Height="300" Width="300">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Thumb DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" Margin="2">
                    <Thumb.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" 
                                       FontSize="{Binding FontSize}" 
                                       Foreground="{Binding Color}"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Thumb.Template>
                    <Thumb.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding OffsetX}" Y="{Binding OffsetY}"/>
                    </Thumb.RenderTransform>
                </Thumb>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MovingWords : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<MovingWordModel> Words { get; set; }

    public MovingWords()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Words = new ObservableCollection<MovingWordModel>
            {
                new MovingWordModel() {Color = "Black", FontSize = 18, Text = "Hello!!"},
                new MovingWordModel() {Color = "Black", FontSize = 18, Text = "This"},
                new MovingWordModel() {Color = "Black", FontSize = 18, Text = "is"},
                new MovingWordModel() {Color = "Black", FontSize = 18, Text = "the"},
                new MovingWordModel() {Color = "Black", FontSize = 18, Text = "Power"},
                new MovingWordModel() {Color = "Black", FontSize = 18, Text = "of"},
                new MovingWordModel() {Color = "Blue", FontSize = 18, Text = "WPF"},
            };

        DataContext = Words;
    }

    private void Thumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        var thumb = sender as Thumb;
        if (thumb == null)
            return;

        var word = thumb.DataContext as MovingWordModel;

        if (word == null)
            return;

        word.OffsetX += e.HorizontalChange;
        word.OffsetY += e.VerticalChange;
    }
}
```

Data Model:

```
public class MovingWordModel:PropertyChangedBase
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int FontSize { get; set; }

    public string Color { get; set; }

    private double _offsetX;
    public Double OffsetX
    {
        get { return _offsetX; }
        set
        {
            _offsetX = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OffsetX");
        }
    }

    private double _offsetY;
    public double OffsetY
    {
        get { return _offsetY; }
        set
        {
            _offsetY = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OffsetY");
        }
    }
}
```

PropertyChangedBase:

```
    public class PropertyChangedBase:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

You can click and drag the words to move them around.

Notice that the values from the dragging will be stored in the `OffsetX` and `OffsetY` properties. The only problem with this approach is that you somewhat lose the Resolution Independence, because the offset values will actually move the words from their default position (which is determined by the `WrapPanel`, therefore they're subject to change depending on the size of the `WrapPanel` itself).

Comment: What would you suggest that would allow me to arrange words any way I like on a work area (a simple rectangle)?  These words can be anywhere, they are not limited to being on rows, or columns.  I.e. truly free-format.  When I place a word, I need to know it's ActualWidth so that I can place another word next to it without overlapping.

Comment: @Sabuncu What will you do afterwards? Do you need to save these new positions? Because you could also use a WrapPanel or something and then apply a `RenderTransform` for the dragging.

Comment: Yes, the words will be put back together into a sentence form, and any changes will need to be saved."Apply a RenderTransform for the dragging" -> goes over my head, I am new to WPF, but with the right guidance, I can tackle it.

Comment: I need PropertyChangedBase to run your code - should I download Caliburn.Micro?

Comment: @Sabancu I'm sorry I forgot to include that. Just added it now.

Comment: UNF***ING BELIEVABLE!!! THANK YOU!  Exactly what I need.  Now I need to study this in depth to figure out how it works.

Comment: @Sabancu remember what I told you about resolution independence. If you will use this code in production you'd better test it in several different screen resolutions.

Comment: Will remember that.  Regardless, it's a solid base to work from and to modify.  (Thank you, I have upvoted every one of your comments here.)

Comment: HighCore, have an additional question: MovingWords' DataContext is set to Words, which is a collection of words.  But when Thumb_DragDelta() gets called, it is passed a single word from this collection through DataContext.  How does WPF do this?  Thanks so much, have been studying your sample code and have already learned a lot.

Comment: @Sabancu The `ItemsControl` takes care of that. Each item that is "drawn" on screen (utilizing the `ItemTemplate`) actually represents 1 item in the `ItemsSource` collection, therefore each of these "pieces of UI" is given the proper `DataContext` to bind to, in the case of the `ItemsControl`, it's contained `items`.

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding}" in XAML works because of the Words = DataContext; assignment in the code-behind, correct?  So ItemsSource is intelligent enough to pass each UI element the currently active item in Words?  Is this a proper recap?  Also, how did you learn WPF?  Any special book, or video, or class, or *any* advice?  Thank you again.

Comment: @Sabancu I love WPF. It's God, then my wife, then my drums and band, then WPF. I don't need books, if you know what I'm saying... With regards to the `DataContext`, yes, that's how it works.

Comment: Thanks.  I feel the same way about WPF, I am humbled by the complexity and the power.

Comment: HighCore, sorry to bother you again, but one more question: your code uses a WrapPanel, which imposes a l-to-r, top-to-bottom ordering on the word elements.  But later, I am able to move those word elements randomly, breaking the order.  How come WrapPanel does not object to this?  Thanks.

Comment: WrapPanel does not notice the movement because the movement happens in the `RenderTransform`, which is applied AFTER the `Layout` has been calculated.